# Python Markdown: How can I config Base URL for Media when markdown string into HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

I have a string:

```
# H1 tag
h1 content is here

![](/media/blog/1551266934_21_289.jpg)
```

As you see, I have an image `![](/media/blog/1551266934_21_289.jpg)` (Same as `![](mydomain.com/media/blog/1551266934_21_289.jpg)`)

When markdown it, it become: `<img src="/media/blog/1551266934_21_289.jpg"/>`

But I want result is using different Base url:

`<img src="https://media.mydomain.com/media/blog/1551266934_21_289.jpg"/>`

Comment: If both of you images are located under `media` directoty, how about using an text editor to replace `/media` to `/media.mydomain.com/media`?

Comment: In localhost and deployment, Media Path is not the same. So I think need to config it from server

Comment: Can you use the HTML `base` tag?

Comment: @MikeRobins no because media server is diffenrent remote server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python-Markdown's [Extension API](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/) and develop a plugin which alters the `src` attribute of all images.

In this specific case, you could override the `image_link` and `image_reference` inline processors by subclassing the `ImageInlineProcessor` and `ReferenceInlineProcessor` classes. But there is no need to alter the parser's behavior. You only need to modify the `src` attribute of all `img` tags. This would be easiest with a [TreeProcessor](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#treeprocessors).

```
from markdown.treeprocessors import Treeprocessor
from urllib.parse import urljoin

BASE = 'https://media.mydomain.com/'

class ImgBaseTreeprocessor(Treeprocessor):
    def run(self, root):
        # Loop through all img elements
        for img in root.getiterator('img'):
            # Join base to the src URL
            img.set('src', urljoin(BASE, img.get('src'))
```

Now you need to tell the `Markdown` class about your new Treeprocessor with an `Extension` subclass:

```
from markdown.extensions import Extension

class ImgBase(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        # register the new treeprocessor with priority 15 (run after 'inline')
        md.treeprocessors.register(ImgBaseTreeprocessor(md), 'imgbase', 15)
```

Finally, you need to tell Markdown to use your new extension:

```
from markdown import markdown

html = markdown(text, extensions=[ImgBase()])
```

There are a few things you might do to improve the extension, which are left as an exercise for the reader:

1. Add a [configuration setting](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#configsettings) to the extension to set the base URL rather than hardcoding it.
2. Do some error checking when joining the base to ensure the existing URL doesn't already have a base.
3. Wrap it up into a Python package to distribute and share with others.

Answer (score -1):

### You can use urlparse to get path of image and can concatenate it with ur HOSTNAME

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HOSTNAME="https://media.mydomain.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    urlInfo = urlparse(img['src'])
    img['src'] = HOSTNAME + urlInfo.path
html_str = str(soup)
```