# Python: Search and Replace all img tag in HTML String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found solution in Python to Search and Replace all `img` tag in HTML String:

I have a HTMl String:

```
"<h1>H1 Tag</h1>\n<p>foo <img alt=\"alt\" src=\"image_2.jpg\
bar</p>\n<p>11</p>\n<h2>H2
Tag</h2>\n<p>ads\nad\nad\nad</p>\n<h3>Imsd</h3>\n<p><img alt=\"alt\"
src=\"image_3.jpg\"
```

I want to Search and Replace all img tag in HTML String by adding base URL `https://domman.com`. So this results I want:

```
"<h1>H1 Tag</h1>\n<p>foo <img alt=\"alt\" src=\"https://domman.com/image_2.jpg\
 bar</p>\n<p>11</p>\n<h2>H2
 Tag</h2>\n<p>ads\nad\nad\nad</p>\n<h3>Imsd</h3>\n<p><img alt=\"alt\"
 src=\"https://domman.com/image_3.jpg\"
```

Comment: Any reason for Python? Why not just use the find and replace functionality of your text editor?

Comment: Because i want to solve this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920208/python-markdown-how-can-i-config-base-url-for-media-when-markdown-string-into-h. Please help me bro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup To replace all src of img tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    img['src'] = 'https://domman.com/'+img['src']
html_str = str(soup)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But could you please take a look my primary issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920208/python-markdown-how-can-i-config-base-url-for-media-when-markdown-string-into-h.

Comment: maybe `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 3):

```
string.replace(r'src=\"', r'src=\"https://domman.com/')
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But could you please take a look my primary issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920208/python-markdown-how-can-i-config-base-url-for-media-when-markdown-string-into-h.

Comment: Shouldn't this be specific to images?

Answer (score 1):

```
import lxml.html
html = lxml.html.fromstring("""<h1>H1 Tag</h1>\n<p>foo <img alt="alt" 
src="image_2.jpg"> 
bar</p><p>11</p>\n<h2>H2 Tag</h2>\n<p>
ads\nad\nad\nad</p>\n<h3>Imsd</h3>\n<p><img alt="alt" src="image_3.jpg">""")
imgs = html.xpath("//img")
for img in imgs:
    img.attrib["src"] = "https://domman.com/" + img.attrib["src"]
with open("page.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(lxml.html.tostring(html))
```

this is it